# How to read value from JSON with Jackson Java

Tags: java, json, jackson-databind

I have a JSON file:

```json
{
    "param": {
        "rows": 1,
        "columns": "4"
    },
    "items": [{
        "name": "A",
        "amount": 33,
        "price": "43"
    }, {
        "name": "B",
        "amount": 43,
        "price": "2"
    }, {
        "name": "C",
        "amount": 45,
        "price": "1"
    }, {
        "name": "D",
        "amount": 543,
        "price": "55" 
   }]
}
```

I want to get the items separately. I try to do, but the result did `null`:

```java
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

Items item; // only items
item =  objectMapper.readValue(new File("D:/example/file.json"), Items.class);
System.out.println(item.getAmount());
```

This is class for Items:

```
public class Items {
    private String name;
    private String amount;
    private double price;

    public Items() {
        super();
    }

    //constructor

    //getters and setters
}
```

What I do wrong? how correctly read value from items?

Comment: You should rename class  `Items` to `Item` and create another class (says `Items`) which has a member variable `List<Item> items`.

Comment: do not understand

Comment: Put another way, when you do the conversion, Jackson is looking to put the fields from the JSON in an object that has and object called `param` and a list of objects that have the `name` , `amount` and `price` fields.
Hence the suggestion to have ab object `Item` to hold this and then include this as the list in the main object

Comment: Your trying to parse the top level element which contains the `param` which is an object and the `items` which is an array into the `Items` class which is incorrect, the `items` array contains an array of items. So @LHCHIN has suggested that you create another class that contains a `List<Item> items` properly and you pass that into the `readValue` method as the class instead of `item`

Comment: You are trying to map a collection `{Items1, Items2, Items3}`, to your class called `Items` which is not a collection but containis only String and double fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't handle the JSON array - **items** - properly, so as I commented under OP, all what you need to do is to rename original class `Items` to `Item` and create another class `Items` as follows, and the `Jackson` library will do the rest for you:

```java
public class Item {
    private String name;
    private String amount;
    private double price;

    // general getters/setters
}

public class Items {
    private List<Item> items;

    // general getter/setter
}
```

Then you can deserialize the JSON string with your code snippet:

```java
Items items = objectMapper.readValue(new File("D:/example/file.json"), Items.class);
System.out.println(items.get(0).getAmount());
```

Answer (score 2):

firstly, you need to have an object, that contain List item, because the JSON file have multiple items, not only one, you can refer my code

```
  public class ItemsList {
    private List<Items> items;

    public ItemsList () {
    }
}
```

and we will modify the mapper

```
        item=  objectMapper.readValue(new File("D:/example/file.json"), ItemsList.class);
```

but i think you should change your class from Items => Item

hope it help you solve problem

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to easily have the following classes, Example.java, Param.java, Item.java:

```
Example.java:

public class Example {
    private Param param;
    private List<Item> items;

    //constructor

    //getters and setters
}


Param.java:

public class Param {

    private int rows;
    private int columns;

    //constructor

    //getters and setters
}

Item.java

public class Item {
    private String name;
    private String amount;
    private double price;
 }
```

Then you can write:

```
 Example  example=  objectMapper.readValue(new File("D:/example/file.json"), 
 Example.class);

  for(Item item: example.getItems())
        System.out.println(item.getAmount());
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem here is because structure of your JSON file is not correspond to the structure of your class that you pass as a second parameter in `ObjectMapper.readValue` method (Items.class in your example). You need to align both structures.
According to the file structure, your `Items` file should looks next

```java
public class Items {
    private Param param;
    private List<Item> items;

    // Getters & Setters
}
```

Additionaly you need to create class `Param`:

```java
public class Param {
    private Integer rows;
    private Integer columns;

    // Getters & Setters
}
```

And class `Item`:

```java
public class Item {
    private String name;
    private String amount;
    private double price;

    // Getters & Setters
}
```

After that you will be able to read your file by next snippet:

```java
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
Items items = objectMapper.readValue(new File("D:/example/file.json"), Items.class);
items.getItems().stream().map(Item::getAmount).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should read it as Map<String, Object> and then use your map to as a source fill your items. Also, there is an open-source library that has a feature based on Jackson library really simplifies reading/writing objects from/to Json. If you have a json string all you have to do is:

```
Map<String, Object> map = JsonUtils.readObjectFromJsonString(jsonString, Map.class);
```

It throws IOException though so you will need to handle it. Here is the [Javadoc](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/utils/JsonUtils.html). The library is called MgntUtils and could be found as [Maven artifact](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.michaelgantman/MgntUtils) and on the [Github](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt/releases) (including javadoc and source code)